# how to enable jquery ui button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui dialog. In the dialog i have 1 save button, when user click on the save button in the callback of the save button i am disabling it. My code :

```
$("#Form1").dialog({
    width: 500, autoOpen: false, modal: true, resizable: false, draggable: false,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function (event, ui) {
            $(event.currentTarget).button({ disabled: true });
             ... .
             ....
         }
    }
    , beforeClose: function () {
        //here how can i enable the save button
    }
});
```

Now my problem is that when user open the dialog again the save button still disabled so thats why i want to enable the button at dialog `beforeClose` event. How can i do this?

Comment: one way might be to save the value of `event.currentTarget` as an attribute of the dialog

Answer (score 1):

The element you invoke the dialog on gets wrapped in a parent so title bar, buttons etc can be added. All the buttons have class `ui-button`

This should do what you need

```
beforeClose:function(){
   $(this).parent().find('.ui-button').button({ disabled: false });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to enable and disable the button in the following way:

```
btn_save = $('#Form1').parent().find(':button:contains("save")');

//disable the save button
$(btn_save).prop('disabled', true).addClass('ui-state-disabled');

//enable the save button
$(btn_save).prop('disabled', false).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

The added css class will give the button it's disabled css styling. Also note that the `:contains` selector is case sensitive.